# Caret: gradient vs gam boosting

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting, caret

What is the difference between a boosted additive model (e.g. caret model: gamboost) and a general stochastic gradient boosting model (caret model: gbm)?

A gradient boosting model is additive by nature, so how does it differ from the gamboost one in the estimation procedure?

Comment: I've found the answer myself: gbm is based on regression trees while gamboost applies GAM as base learners (they can either be linear, smooth, etc.). They're both additive models but the choice of base learners change.

Comment: Congrats on answering your own question and answering it. You might want to post it as an answer so it can be properly upvoted. (Welcome to the CV community!) (Unfortunately you cannot upvote your own answers :) )

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer myself: gbm is based on regression trees while gamboost applies GAM as base learners (they can either be linear, smooth, etc.). They're both additive models but the choice of base learners change.